# How to get the contents of a folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I get the contents of a folder in my bucket please using javascript? If I had lets say one folder with just one csv file in it I would like to get for example, name, size and path of the csv.

Comment: Write code. Once you have a problem post a question. Google provides SDKs, APIs, etc, and examples to start with.

Comment: Where are you running your Javascript code - in the browser or on the server using node.js? If in the browser how do you authorize users to access Cloud Storage? Those details are why I posted a comment.

Comment: You have several tutorial to read file, according to a prefix, in GCS. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

- There are Google recommended [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) available to achieve
  this. For e.g. you can have a look at the [code example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#code-samples) for listing
  files in a bucket using NodeJS. These need setting up authentication,
  which is also explained in the documentation.
- You can read more about how Google Cloud Storage folders work at the
  following [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)
- Additionally, you may want to go through this [code example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-nodejs) for
  viewing object metadata in Cloud Storage bucket using NodeJS.